# My timer label takes up a new number after scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, timer, tableview, countdowntimer

[image: Screenshot]

My timer label takes up a new number after scrolling or reloding `tableview`, and at the same time it shows a few numbers per second. Can anyone help i want my label show on ?

I want my label to show only the number that it first comes in

In the pictures that you see, after a scroll or a relay table, the timers display several values ​​per second every second.
I put my codes and pictures

```
import Alamofire
import Foundation

class Games: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var gamesTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Alamofire.request("http://188.158.121.200:3030/shans.com/get_main_room_list", method:.post, headers: headers).responseJSON { (newresponse) in
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let response = try decoder.decode(Root1.self, from: newresponse.data!)
                switch(response.joinedUser) {
                case  .joinedUserElementArray( let arr):
                    AppDelegate.AllofGames_Ids = arr.map { $0.id }
                case .string( _) :
                    break
                }
                if AppDelegate.AllofGames.isEmpty == true {
                    for each in response.allRooms {
                        let epocTime = TimeInterval(Int(each.matchTime)!) / 1000
                        if each.finished == true || AppDelegate.AllofGames_Ids.contains(each.id)  {
                            //Do nothing
                        }else {
                            let structGames = StructAllofGames(finished: each.finished, pic: each.pic, _id: each.id, coininput: each.coinInput, Award_money: each.awardMoney, Award_coin: each.awardCoin, Match_time: Int(epocTime), Winner_number: each.winnerNumber, Free: each.capacity.free, Total: each.capacity.total)
                            AppDelegate.AllofGames.append(structGames)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                self.gamesTableView.reloadData()
                            }//dispatch
                        }//else
                    }
                } else {
                    print("fk")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return AppDelegate.AllofGames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let Cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableview1", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

        Cell.SekeVorudi.text = String(AppDelegate.AllofGames[indexPath.row].coininput)
        Cell.jaize.text =  String(AppDelegate.AllofGames[indexPath.row].Award_money) + "تومان"
        Cell.ZarfiatOtagh.text = String(AppDelegate.AllofGames[indexPath.row].Total) + "/" + String(AppDelegate.AllofGames[indexPath.row].Free)
        Cell.TedadBarande.text = String(AppDelegate.AllofGames[indexPath.row].Winner_number)
        let  Fulllink    = AppDelegate.AllofGames[indexPath.row].pic
        Cell.imageview.downloaded(from: Fulllink)
        let (h,m,s)  = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(seconds: AppDelegate.AllofGames[indexPath.row].Match_time)
        let HoursToMinute = h * 60
        let AllOfMinutes = HoursToMinute + m
        Cell.timer(m: AllOfMinutes, s: 0)
        return Cell
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

and my codes in tableview cell:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var timelabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SekeVorudi: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var jaize: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TedadBarande: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ZarfiatOtagh: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func timer(m: Int, s: Int) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            var hour : Int = m/60
            var minute : Int = m % 60
            var second : Int = s

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.timelabel.text = (String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second))
            }

            while true {
                sleep(1)
                if hour == 0 && minute == 0 && second == 0 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                            self.timelabel.alpha = 0
                        })
                    }
                } else if second == 0 {
                    if minute != 0 {
                        minute = minute - 1
                        second = 59
                    } else if second == 0 && minute == 0 {
                        hour = hour - 1
                        minute = 59
                        second = 59
                    }
                } else if second != 0 {
                    second = second - 1
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.timelabel.text = (String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an optional variable on the top of your `UIViewController` and set its value to your desired cell number, and in `CellForRowAt` check that value if it was `nil`, if not set your label to that number, if its `nil` just keep going normally as you usually do.

This problem mainly caused from queuing cells out of `UITableView` when you scroll cells get dequeued and therefore calling `CellForRowAt` so it reset the default data, in your case resetting the `UILabel` value again.

In your case i recommend setting the timer out side that function/cell, so you can normally use that value without resetting.

Comment: welcome to SO, well you have to understand the problem first rather just asking for a code here, usually the community doesn't like to get asked for code, i recommend understanding the problem so it wont happen to you again in the future, altho you can ask me what part you didnt understand